# How can I create API connection to Azure KeyVault when deploying Logic App from ARM template in DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I am deploying Logic App workflow through ARM template in DevOps, which works great. When I need to connect to Blob storage or Storage Queue in the workflow, I am able to create these two API connections in ARM beforehand and then use them, but how can I create connection to KeyVault? The (I believe only required) connection parameters for the connection Template are `vaultName` and `token` as shown below. The whole template is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jankuc/6b96c9c97828edd807d4d8fd67a97673).

```js
"connectionParameters": {
    "vaultName": {
        "type": "string",
        "uiDefinition": {
            "displayName": "Vault name",
            "description": "Name of the vault",
            "tooltip": "Provide name of the vault",
            "constraints": {
                "required": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    "token": {
        "type": "oauthSetting",
        "oAuthSettings": {
            "identityProvider": "aadcertificate",
            "clientId": "7ab7862c-4c57-491e-8a45-d52a7e023983",
            "scopes": [],
            "redirectMode": "Direct",
            "redirectUrl": "https://logic-apis-westeurope.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect",
            "properties": {
                "IsFirstParty": "True"
            },
            "customParameters": {
                "tenantId": {},
                "resourceUri": {
                    "value": "https://vault.azure.net"
                },
                "loginUriAAD": {
                    "value": "https://login.windows.net"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // <other input parameters>
}
```

But where can I get/find the token? Is it possible to somehow use the token that DevOps is using to deploy the infrastructure? Or get the token any other non-interactive way e.g. from powershell script?
Any pointeres will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the managed identity support has not yet been added to the Key Vault connector, there is a workaround. You can use HTTP connector with managed identity and use Key Vault REST API to get the secrets.

This is explained for example in this blog post: https://blog.eldert.net/retrieve-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-logic-apps-using-managed-identity/

Answer (score 1):

Managed Identity support has been added to the Key Vault connector. More details can be found in the following blog post - https://aztoso.com/logic-app/keyvault-connector-with-managed-identity/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [Managed Identity (MSI) for Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity)

Essentially this will create an identity in your Azure Active Directory for the application thus eliminating the token process.  This identity is assigned a thumbprint in azure so if it is destroyed and recreated the identity's thumbprint will be recreated. If deploying via ARM just add the identity section to your Logic App:

```
{
   "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
   "type": "Microsoft.logic/workflows",
   "name": "[variables('logicappName')]",
   "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
   "identity": {
      "type": "SystemAssigned"
   }
```

For the Key Vault if deploying via the same ARM template you can add an access policy for the Resource ID like below (specifically the objectID section). I would advise a depends on statement as outlined so the Access Policy isn't assigned until after the MSI is created.

```
 "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantID": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
            "permissions": {
              "secrets": [
                "get"
              ],
              "keys": [
                "get"
              ],
              "certificates": [
                "import"
              ]
            },
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('WebsiteName'))]"
            ]
          }
        ]
```

After completing this your Logic App should have access to the secrets in the Key Vault w/o any additional configuration.

Comment: Have they added managed identity support for Key Vault connector yet? At least it hasn't been added to the documentation. (https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity)

Comment: You might be correct. Full disclosure is I looked at this from strictly Logic App and granting said Logic App access to a Key Vault.  This did not take into account the Connector not supporting said action. I noticed the documentation you reference has been updated this week. I ran a test with the connector to a key vault which my ID did not have an access policy associated with the but the MSI did and it returned success.....Maybe Microsoft has something coming out on this soon?

Comment: Sure hope so, that would make the connector much more useful...